# Topology of $\sin \frac 1 x$

Tags: general-topology, continuity, epsilon-delta

Let $d$ be the usual Euclidean metric on $\Bbb R$ and $f: (\Bbb R, d) \mapsto ([-1,1],d)$ be the map given by $f(x) = \left\{ \begin{matrix} 0, & x=0 \\ \sin \frac 1 x, & x \neq 0 \end{matrix} \right.$.

I need to show that $f$ is not continuous at $0$.

My attempt:

Suppose $f$ is continuous at $0$.

Since $f$ is continuous at $0$ then $\exists$ $N(x,\epsilon)$ such that $N(x,\epsilon)$ $\subset$ $f^{-1}([-1,1])$. Take $\epsilon = \frac 1 2$.
Then $N(x,\frac 1 2) \subset f^{-1}([-1,1])$. However, the $N(-\frac 1 2, \frac 1 2)$ contains points outside of $f^{-1}([-1,1])$.

My question is this: What is the best method to prove this? By best I mean intuitively, not necessarily concisely. My goal was to find a neighborhood that was not included in the inverse but I feel that I messed up somewhere on the way.

Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a much simpler way. Consider the two sequences $x_n = \dfrac 1 {2n \pi}$ and $y_n = \dfrac 1 {2n\pi + \frac \pi 2}$. They both tend to $0$, but $f(x_n) = \sin 2n\pi = 0 \to 0$ and $f(y_n) = \sin (2n\pi + \frac \pi 2) = 1 \to 1$, which shows that $f$ doesn't even have a limit in $0$, let alone be continuous there.

Comment: It's possible the original poster is not allowed to use sequences, since their use seems to me so obviously the way you'd want to approach this particular result. Maybe the original poster can clarify the rules of engagement for this problem.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro I am studying for final exams, using the book Undergraduate Topology by Robert Kasriel. Use of sequences are not discouraged, I think that I am just more comfortable using neighborhoods so that's the approach I began with. As Alex M. showed above, sequences are a much neater way to show this. Thank you!

Comment: @Melody: This is the standard proof of this (popular) exercise, I believe most maths students encounter it. Add it to your inventory of proof techniques!

Comment: @Melody: FYI, Kasriel was my first topology book, and I'm surprised someone even knows about it now. (I later went through almost all of Munkres, all of Willard, and bits and pieces of Kelly and Engelking.) It was a good book choice for me at the time, although I rarely find myself using it for reference now. I posted some comments about Kasriel in [this 28 March 2006 sci.math post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=4594852).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro: I don't want to drift offtopic, but there's also [a 2009 edition](https://books.google.ro/books?id=YPKNPwAACAAJ) of that book. Since I don't have it at hand, does it also include uniform spaces?

Comment: @Alex M.: You're in luck. I decided to bring my copy with me to work today just in case I needed to look at it. No, it doesn't have uniform spaces. The last 3 chapters are: 9. Quotient Spaces (pp. 230-247); 10. Net and Filter Convergence (pp. 248-260); 11. Product Spaces (pp. 261-275). My copy is the 1971 W. B. Saunders Company edition. I didn't realize yesterday it was reprinted by Dover Publications (in 2009), and this explains why "someone even knows about it now". Actually, according my my notes in my copy, it was previously (in 1977) reprinted by Robert E. Krieger Publishing Company.